# flac2mp3 on mac?

Tags: macos, conversion, mp3, flac

What tools are there to convert flac to mp3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html), which can convert directly to and from a variety of audio formats, including FLAC, MP3, AAC, and Apple Lossless. It's available both as a command line tool and a regular GUI app. And best of all, it's free!

Comment: XLD is awesome, just what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. This is the new one: http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html

Answer (score 1):

There are links [here](http://flac.sourceforge.net/download.html) for downloads.  These will not convert to .mp3.  However, you can convert the flac files to wav, and then using iTunes (or something else, but you are on a mac..) you can then convert the wav files to mp3.

Answer (score -1):

Why convert? You will lose quality if you re-encode your music.

Your question should be how to play flac on the mac.

Comment: -1 Not all devices can play flac.