# How to Play 24 bit flac on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, flac, aac, lossless, alac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flac files on iTunes](https://superuser.com/questions/66171/flac-files-on-itunes)

I have flac files, which are 24 bit.

I have tried to convert them to MPEG-4 Audio (Apple lossless), using Max (on Mac OS 10.6.4), but it let me choose only the bitrate (16-320) and quality(Low-Maximum). I think, all the quality will be gone this way.

Also, it does not converts the files, because of an error, it shows:

> The call to ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed.

Comment: look at http://superuser.com/questions/143066/flac-to-whatever-mp3-mp4-wav-converter-for-mac http://superuser.com/questions/8235/flac2mp3-on-mac

Comment: Apple Lossless support 24-bit and up to 192khz (but it does not support more than 2 channels). If your software does not work, try something else. I'm on windows and use dBPowerAmp to convert 24-bit FLAC to 24-bit M4A without any problem. The other answers mentions XLD.